# Printing postscript and raw data to line printer generates excess top margins

Tags: printing, postscript, cups

We have a custom application which when printing under Unix pipes a PDF file through Adobe's acroread Unix command to generate a PostScript file, and then sends it to the printers using the lp command. I've been dealing now for a while with a line printer, an old Epson LX-300+, that is used in one of our customers to print continuous check forms -- the printer generates an excess blank margin on the top of the form and prevents me from printing in key locations of the preprinted forms.

I've tried just about anything I could get my hands on. I'm using a custom PPD so I could set the custom page size we require for these continuous forms. I've even tried printing raw text to the printer using lp -o raw and it still generates blank space up top.

This is the lines I added to the PPD to set the custom page size:

```
*PageSize Checks/Checks: "<</PageSize[596 227]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
...
*PageRegion Checks/Checks: "<</PageSize[596 227]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
...
*ImageableArea Checks/Checks: "0 0 596 227"
...
*PaperDimension Checks/Checks: "596 227"
```

I even attempted modifying the HWMargins setting from:

```
*HWMargins: 36 36 36 36
```

to

```
*HWMargins: 0 0 0 0
```

to no avail.

Is there something limiting me? Can I add some form of ESC/PCL/PJL command to override what it certainly looks like the printer's hardware limits? Keep in mind this very printer model is currently being used to print checks, and it's using raw data, though it is doing it via Windows and I don't have access to the methods it is using.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is the "excess blank margin" to which you object?  How big is the vertical margin from perforation to first printed mark when this printer prints checks?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [*User Manual* for the Epson LX-300 Impact Printer](http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/lx300_/lx300_u1.pdf), p. A-5, the minimum top margin from the perforation on continuous-feed forms is 9.0mm (0.35 inches), while the minimum top margin on a single sheet is 5.3mm (0.2 inches).  Is the excess blank margin the software gives you larger than this?

The Epson LX-300 is a 9-pin impact printer, controlled with the ESC/P language. It does not have a PostScript interpreter. Are you sure that *acroread* is sending PostScript language output to the printer?  The printer can either receive character data from the computer, or image data. It sounds like the check-printing software uses the printer in character data mode. I expect that Adobe's *acroread* software generates output that puts the printer in image mode. Thus *acroread* is exercising a much different mode of the printer than the check printing.

I suggest you try printing to the printer from *acroread*, trying to find a PDF file which prints with the margins you seek. Try authoring PDF files in a word processor or in Adobe Illustrator. Try setting the page size and page margins of the PDF file. See if you can get *acroread* to use the margins you want in any circumstance. If you can't, then maybe there is no easy way to get the margins you want using your app upstream of *acroread*.

The [FAQ, *What are the most commonly used escape codes?*](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&infoType=FAQ&oid=14245&prodoid=8237&foid=38597&cat=30930&subcat=30935), gives a few of the escape codes for this language. More commands are in a section starting on page A-10 of the User's Manual. The FAQ adds, "If you need to use advanced escape codes for programming purposes, you can purchase an ESC/P Reference Manual from EPSON Accessories."

You don't mention whether the printer is set up with the form perforation in the correct position. It probably is, but just in case, there's an [FAQ, *The printer is not starting at the right position on the paper. How can I change the top-of-form?*](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?BV_UseBVCookie=yes&infoType=FAQ&oid=14245&prodoid=8237&foid=38603)

The [Epson LX-300 Impact Printer Support Page](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=14245&prodoid=8237) has links to a variety of information, as well as the Product Information Guide. You might find other helpful information there. Good luck!

Comment: Our tool authors its own PDFs and it is generated without such a large margin up top (almost 1 cm). As I mentioned in the question, the same margin is generated when printing raw data.

I've gone over the current Windows production printer and it seems they are using an Okidata driver instead of the LX-300+ one. With the LX-300+, if I try to print through Acrobat under Windows, it generates the same hard margin, but it doesn't do it with the Oki driver. I'll see if I can use an Oki PPD to get the results I need on Linux.